# Google's SERP breadcrumb returning a `null` value for page despite returning correct schema markup in googles structured data testing tool

Tags: seo, microdata, json-ld, structured-data

We see the following search engine listing for a [page](https://www.globalknowledge.com/us-en/training/course-catalog/brands/itil/). Note that the breadcrumbs includes a `null` value.

[Image of SERP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psaUM.png)

[Google Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOa9X.png)

However, when testing that page's DOM in the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0), we see that all the right values in the breadcrumbs found in the JSON+LD schema.

[Schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suzue.png)

Does this mean that the Google listing is out of date? Or, is there something I am missing?

Comment: I suspect it may the the presence of the special character in "ITIL®", and maybe a bug with Google. Have you recently dropped the item with that character from your markup? That may have stopped the issue.

Comment: I don't think that's it because it showed up correctly on SERP 2 days ago with the special character. Also, this is a problem across several pages - pages without special characters at all.